# What is the main difference between Collection and Collections in Java?

Tags: java, collections

What is the main difference between Collection and Collections in Java?

Comment: a little javadoc now and then hasn't hurt anyone..

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`Collection` is a base interface for most collection classes, whereas `Collections` is a utility class. I recommend you read the documentation.

Comment: Which would be:
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

Comment: Or, for Java 8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

Answer (score 24):

Are you asking about the [Collections](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class versus the classes which implement the [Collection](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface?

If so, the Collections class is a utility class having static methods for doing operations on objects of classes which implement the Collection interface. For example, Collections has methods for finding the max element in a Collection.

The Collection interface defines methods common to structures which hold other objects. List and Set are subinterfaces of Collection, and ArrayList and HashSet are examples of concrete collections.

Answer (score 17):

***collection*** : A collection(with small 'c') represents a group of objects/elements.

`Collection` : The root [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) of [Java Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

`Collections` : A  utility class that is a member of the  [Java Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html).

Comment: *one of* the root interfaces.

Comment: First line in the Collection documentation: "The root interface in the collection hierarchy"

Answer (score 13):

[`Collection`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), as its javadoc says is "*The root interface in the collection hierarchy.*" This means that every single class implementing `Collection` in any form is part of the [Java Collections Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html).

The Collections Framework is Java's native implementation of data structure classes (*with implementation specific properties*) which represent a group of objects which are somehow related to each other and thus can be called a collection.

[`Collections`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) is merely an utility method class for doing certain operations, for example adding thread safety to your [ArrayList](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instance by doing this:

```
List<MyObj> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new Arraylist<MyObj>());
```

The main difference in my opinion is that `Collection` is base interface which you may use in your code as a type for object (*although I wouldn't directly recommend that*) while `Collections` just provides useful operations for handling the collections.

Comment: Of course, now `Iterable` is the root interface of the collection hierarchy.

Comment: I'd say that Iterable is the root interface of the iterable hierarchy. :)

Comment: Iterator is a generalized view to a collection, how'd that sound? :)

Answer (score 12):

`Collection` is an interface containing `List`, `Set` and `Queue`.

`Collections` is a class containing useful methods like `Collections.sort()` and  `Collections.synchronizedlist()`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Collection is an root interface of Java collection framework.
Collections is a utility class which contains static methods. example Collections.sort()

Answer (score 2):

Collection, as its javadoc says is "The root interface in the collection hierarchy." This means that every single class implementing Collection in any form is part of the Java Collections Framework.

The Collections Framework is Java's native implementation of data structure classes (with implementation specific properties) which represent a group of objects which are somehow related to each other and thus can be called a collection.

Collections is merely an utility method class for doing certain operations, for example adding thread safety to your ArrayList instance by doing this:

List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new Arraylist());

The main difference in my opinion is that Collection is base interface which you may use in your code as a type for object (although I wouldn't directly recommend that) while Collections just provides useful operations for handling the collections.

Answer (score 2):

Collection is an Interface which can used to Represent a Group of Individual object as a single Entity.

Collections is an utility class to Define several Utility Methods for Collection object.

Answer (score 2):

Collection is a interface which is used to represent group of individual object as a single entity.

Collections is an utility class present in java.util. package to define several utility method (like sorting,searching ) for collection object.

Answer (score 1):

Collection is a base interface for most collection classes (it is the root interface of java collection framework) 
Collections is a utility class

Collections class is a utility class having static methods It implements Polymorphic algorithms which operate on collections.

Answer (score 1):

The `Collections` class is a utility class having static methods for doing operations on objects of classes which implement the `Collection` interface. For example, Collections has methods for finding the max element in a `Collection.`

Answer (score 1):

Collection is an interface from which other class forms like List, Set are derived.
Collections (with "S") is a utility class having static methods to simplify work on collection. Ex : Collections.sort()

Answer (score 1):

As per Java Doc **Collection** is:

> The root interface in the collection hierarchy. A collection represents a group of objects, known as its elements. Some collections allow duplicate elements and others do not. Some are ordered and others unordered. The JDK does not provide any direct implementations of this interface: it provides implementations of more specific subinterfaces like Set and List. This interface is typically used to pass collections around and manipulate them where maximum generality is desired.

Where as **Collections** is:

> This class consists exclusively of static methods that operate on or return collections. It contains polymorphic algorithms that operate on collections, "wrappers", which return a new collection backed by a specified collection, and a few other odds and ends.

Answer (score 0):

Collections is a class which has some static methods and that method returns the collection.
Collection is an interface,rather than root interface in collection hierarchy.

Comment: Hi titas. The same answer was answered by @Luno and accepted three years ago. No need to repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Collections is a utilty class providing many static methods for operations like sorting... whereas Collection in a top level interface.

Answer (score 0):

Collection is a interface and Collections is class in Java.util package

Answer (score 0):

**Collections** is a utility class, meaning that it defines a set of methods that perform common, often re-used functions, such as sorting a list, rotating a list, finding the minimum value etc.
And these common methods are defined under static scope.

**Collection** is an interface that is implemented by AbstractCollection which in turn is implemented by AbstractList, AbstractSet etc.

Also,
Collections class has thirty-two convenience implementations of its collection interfaces, providing unmodifiable collections,
synchronized collections. Nearly all of these implementations are
exported via static factory methods in one noninstantiable class (java.util.Collections).

**Reference: Effective Java**

Answer (score -2):

collection is an interface and it is a root  interface for all classes and interfaces like set,list and map.........and all the interfaces can implement collection interface.

Collections is a class that can also implements collection interface.......

Comment: downvote for `Collections is a class that can also implements collection interface....... `

Mind that `Collections` is a utility class