# Why methods from Collections were not put in AbstractCollection?

Tags: java, collections

I'm wondering why class `Collections` was created. Theoritically methods from this class could be put in class `AbstractCollection`. So what was the reason seperate utils class was created?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Java Collection and Collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796275/difference-between-java-collection-and-collections)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate.  This is `Collections` vs. `AbstractCollection`.  The linked question is `Collection` vs `Collections`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Not every collection extends `AbstractCollection`, and those methods are still applicable there.
2. Having too many methods in the same class makes it harder to understand that class when you're working your way through the Javadoc.
3. If you're receiving an `Collection` from an untrusted caller, being sure that you're always using the same implementation of e.g. `unmodifiableCollection` can be helpful.
4. Most of the time, you don't keep track of the exact implementation type of collections: for example, you write `Set<E> set = new HashSet<>();`  In this case, you won't be able to use any methods defined in `AbstractCollection` that aren't in `Collection`.

Comment: Could you give an example which `Collection` class does not extends `AbstractCollection`?

Comment: I'm not sure there are any examples in the JDK, but third-party projects like [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) do it all the time: for example, the `ImmutableCollection` hierarchy and the `ForwardingCollection` hierarchy don't extend `AbstractCollection`.

Comment: @mich, you could implement your own Collection which doesn't extend AbstractCollection. That would be an example of a non-AbstractCollection Collection.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a time you want to implement an independent Object which implements the one of the `Collection` interface, without extending AbstractCollection.

For example:  http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/bag/HashBag.html

Comment: Well, let's be fair: that's because `Bag` deliberately violates the `Collection` contract.

Answer (score 0):

When the JDK folks decide that they want to add more methods to the Collections class they simply have to implement them.  newSetFromMap was added in 1.6, for example.  They cannot add more methods to the Collection interface and maintain backwards compatibility because, as Louis Wasserman said, not all collections extend AbstractCollection - specifically the third party ones that are part of Guava, Commons Collections, Hibernate, OpenJPA, etc.

This isn't nearly as big of a problem in languages that have mixins instead of interfaces.  Scala, for instance, has a huge number of methods on its collections.  So many, in fact, that you run into Louis Wasserman's number two issue of difficult to read javadoc (scaladoc in this case.)